# Spark application gets KILLED abruptly in EMR after 1 hour and livy session expires.What is the cause& solution?

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, livy

I am using JupyterHub on AWS EMR cluster. I am using EMR version 5.16

I submitted a spark application using a pyspark3 notebook.
My application is trying to write 1TB data to s3.
I am using autoscaling feature of the EMR to scale us the task node.

Hardware configurations:
1.Master node:32 GB RAM with 16 cores
2.Core node:32 GB RAM with 16 cores
3.Task node:16 GB with 8 cores each. (Task nodes scales up 15)

I have observed that Spark application gets killed after running for 50 to 60 minutes.
I tried debugging:
1. My cluster still had scope for scaling up. So it is not an issue with a shortage of resources.
2. Livy session also gets killed.
3. In the job log, I saw error message RECVD TERM SIGNAL "Shutdown hook 
received"

Please note:
1. I have kept :spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true"
2. I am using the yarn fair scheduler with user impersonation in Jupiter hub

Can you please help me in understanding the problem and solution for it?

Comment: hey did you find out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I faced the same problem and I found the solution thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240619/7807920).

The issue comes from the Livy configuration parameter `livy.server.session.timeout`, which sets the timeout for a session by default to 1 hour.

You should set it by adding the following line into the configurations of the EMR cluster.

```
[{'classification': 'livy-conf','Properties': {'livy.server.session.timeout':'5h'}}]
```

This solved the issue for me.