# how to set livy.server.session.timeout on EMR cluster boostrap?

Tags: configuration, amazon-emr, livy

I am creating an EMR cluster, and using jupyter notebook to run some spark tasks.
My tasks die after approximately 1 hour of execution, and the error is:

```
An error was encountered:
Invalid status code '400' from https://xxx.xx.x.xxx:18888/sessions/0/statements/20 with error payload: "requirement failed: Session isn't active."
```

My understanding is that it is related to the Livy config `livy.server.session.timeout`, but I don't know how I can set it in the bootstrap of the cluster (I need to do it in the bootstrap because the cluster is created with no ssh access)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On EMR, `livy-conf` is the classification for the properties for livy's `livy.conf` file, so when creating an EMR cluster, choose `advanced options` with Livy as an application chosen to install, please pass this EMR configuration in the `Enter Configuration` field.

```
[{'classification': 'livy-conf','Properties': {'livy.server.session.timeout':'5h'}}]
```

- On EMR, Livy binary is located at `/etc/livy/`, and so the config file is at `/etc/livy/conf/livy.conf`

To verify this,

- Create an EMR cluster with a known `ec2 key-pair`, Livy and above config
- Using the ec2 `key-pair`, login to the EC2 Master node associated with the cluster `ssh -i some-ec2-key-pair.pem hadoop@ec2-00-00-00-0.ca-region-n.compute.amazonaws.com`
- Navigate to `/etc/livy/conf`, vim `livy.conf` & see the updated value of `livy.server.session.timeout`

Comment: Replace 'classification' with 'Classification'.

Comment: how can we change livy.rsc.launcher.port.range property in livy-client.conf ? unable to do so, classification "livy-client" or "livy-client-conf" is not working.

Comment: Hi @Naveen, you can add this link to your answer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-session-not-found-http-request-error/

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want the Livy session to go down at all, then set the property `livy.server.session.timeout-check` to `false` in `/etc/livy/conf/livy.conf`.

Comment: Using AWS console EMR page for my cluster, I'm able to edit table and add configuration for all instance groups, using `livy-conf` and `livy.server.session.timeout-check`, `false`.  The master and core go into 'reconfiguring' mode after.

Comment: @Merlin, my Master and Core went into "Reconfiguring" status for a while, then the master became "Suspended" and the core "Running". There's a warning that says "Master Instance Group: Configuration reversion failed, arrest instance group." Is that what happened to you?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that if you don’t want to recreate the cluster is:
go to `/etc/livy/conf/livy.conf` and set the `livy.server.session.timeout` property to the value you would like.
After that, run `sudo restart livy-server` to make the configuration applied.

Comment: That command does not work for restart. Better use this:
```sudo systemctl restart livy-server```

Comment: Whats the time unit of timeout? Seconds?