# Pyspark: Invalid status code '400' when lazy loading the dataframe

Tags: python, memory, pyspark

I am having
`Invalid status code '400'`  errors with every time I tried to `show` the pyspark dataframe. My AWS sagemaker driver and executor memory are 32G.

-Env:

```
Python version : 3.7.6
pyspark version : '2.4.5-amzn-0'
Notebook instance : 'ml.t2.2xlarge'
```

-EMR cluster config

```
{"classification":"livy-conf","properties":{"livy.server.session.timeout":"5h"}},
{"classification":"spark-defaults","properties":{"spark.driver.memory":"20G"}}
```

After some manipulation, I cleaned data and reduced the data size.
The dataframe should be correct

```
print(df.count(), len(df.columns))
print(df.show())
```

```
(1642, 9)

 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff    ...
  VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01     1132       ...
  VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03     465        ...
  VOD      01-02   10:04    0.02     245
  VOD      01-02   10:15    0.01     364     
  VOD      01-02   10:04    0.02     12
```

However if I continue to do filtering,

```
new_df= df.filter(f.col('time_diff')<= 1800)
new_df.show()
```

then I got this error

```
An error was encountered:
Invalid status code '400' from http://11.146.133.8:8990/sessions/34/statements/8 with error payload: {"msg":"requirement failed: Session isn't active."}
```

I really have no idea whats going on.

Can someone please advise ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your session is time out and there is a lots of reason causing it time out. Although it's from the EMR, this post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062824/session-isnt-active-pyspark-in-an-aws-emr-cluster

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan . I followed those posts as per suggested. Updated livy time out and driver memory, but the issue still exist.

Comment: Hi @FlyUFalcon, could you share more about: 1. The original size of your `df` 2. How do you save your data (`parquet` or `csv` or ...)? 3. How many partition do you have in your df? 4. Do you have any data skewness? As you mentioned, you call some `action` like `count()` and `show()` and it's still work at this moment but failed after further processing, I believe it should relate to insufficient memory or single partition transformation overload your executor.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan , dataframe shape is (1642, 9) .  After I converted it to pandas, the memory usage is  109.2+ KB. Thx.

Comment: Hi @FlyUFalcon, 109.2+ KB is your source data size or after transformation? How do you save your source data and how many partition do you have when you read the dataset?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan , 
Yes. 109.2+ KB is the  data after converting it to pandas. 
If I apply ' print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) ' 

I have output: '1'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this error before, but as you mentioned that you have only `1` partition and you got this error in the process but not at the beginning, I believe it should relate to the OOM issue.

Please try to do the repartition based on the total number of core you use:

```
# read the data, let say you are reading the parquet file and you have total 20 cores
df = spark.read.parquet("/path/of/your/data")
df = df.repartition(20)
```

Also if your dataframe will be reused, you should use the `df.persist()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change livy.server.session.timeout parameter.
Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220381/how-to-set-livy-server-session-timeout-on-emr-cluster-boostrap?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C58.9137) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227156/spark-application-gets-killed-abruptly-in-emr-after-1-hour-and-livy-session-expi/56170127?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C29.7083#56170127)

Comment: Thanks
Yes. I already did that in my cluster config.

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching for results.
I finally got the answer to solve the question.
I dont know what wrong with my config setting, but I need to update drivermemory in spark terminal.

just upgrade the memory form there, and the issue will be gone.

[image]

[image]